# Facebook Sdk 4.0 Email is empty

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

In Android Studio Project ,used Facebook Sdk 4.0 . **Email** Field always returns **empty** ,even added permissions to access email of user. (Used Graph Api).

Return well in other properties like name,id,link .

this is my code ,

```
       loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

            GraphRequest request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                    loginResult.getAccessToken(),
                    new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(
                                JSONObject object,
                                GraphResponse response) {

                            if (response.getError() != null) {
                                // handle error
                            }
                            else {

                                String email = object.optString("email");
                                int id = object.optInt("id");
                                String name = object.optString("name");


                            }


                        }
                    });
            Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
            parameters.putString("fields", "id,name,email");
            request.setParameters(parameters);
            request.executeAsync();


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {

            info.setText("Login attempt canceled.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {

            info.setText("Login attempt failed.");
        }
    });
```

**Gradle**

```
   dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
   }
```

Comment: Does the user have an email address on file with Facebook? (Not necessarily the case, if they signed up using their mobile.) Also, the email needs to be verified, otherwise it won’t be returned. And there are a few edge cases with privacy settings, where you don’t get an email returned, even if the user accepted the permission. // The long and short of it, your app should never _rely_ on getting an email address from Facebook; if you _need_ one, then you should implement an additional step where users can enter an email address manually.

Comment: user has email address

Comment: And the user have verified their email address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u add setReadPermissions?

```
loginButton.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("public_profile, email, user_friends"));
```